# Spring boot unable to find bean OAuth2AuthorizedClientService

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, keycloak

I am building an OIDC client with webflux and keycloak. My spring app wont start as it cant find the bean below:

```
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientService' in your configuration.
```

now then...

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:2.0.3.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client"
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools"

    compile group: 'org.keycloak', name: 'keycloak-services', version: '4.0.0.Final'
    compile group: 'org.keycloak', name: 'keycloak-admin-client', version: '4.0.0.Final'

    compile "org.projectlombok:lombok"
    compile group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', name: 'resteasy-jackson2-provider', version: '4.0.0.Beta4'

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-id: your-app-client-id
            client-secret: your-app-client-secret
          facebook:
            client-id: your-app-client-id
            client-secret: your-app-client-secret
          keycloak:
            provider: keycloak
            client-id: auth-api
            client-secret: 727bea9d-6e01-433a-960b-83ac5d939adf
            client-name: auth-api
            client-authentication-method: basic
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri-template: '{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}'
            scope:
              - openid
              - profile
              - email

        provider:
          keycloak:
            authorization-uri: http://70.314.280.xxx/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth
            token-uri: http://70.314.280.xxx/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
            user-info-uri: http://70.314.280.xxx/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
            jwk-set-uri: http://70.314.280.xxx/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/certs
            user-name-attribute: preferred_username
```

Clearly it cant create the ClientRegistration object but not sure why spring wont pick the oauth2 settings section from the yaml file?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The space between `- email` and `provider:`could be a problem.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz Thanks but that isn't the problem.

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar: I am facing the same issue. How did you resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue today, debugging the source is very easy with Spring + IntelliJ as usual, the reason is this line of code:

```java
map.from(properties::getRedirectUri).to(builder::redirectUriTemplate);
```

The code can also be found here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.java#L57

So, You should not be using `redirect-uri-template` but `redirect-uri` in your yaml file. 
I fell into this issue following a tutorial and pasting their yaml file.